# Shut off php strict reporting in production

Tags: apache2, php, php-ini

I am getting these errors from php:

```
Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class WP_Widget in /home/kyle/WordPressDev/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 93

Strict Standards: Non-static method AisisCore_Loader_AutoLoader::get_instance() should not be called statically in /home/kyle/WordPressDev/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/CoreTheme/Setup.php on line 6

Strict Standards: Accessing static property AisisCore_Template_Builder::$_options as non static in /home/kyle/WordPressDev/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/AisisCore/Template/Builder.php on line 51

Strict Standards: Accessing static property AisisCore_Template_Builder::$_options as non static in /home/kyle/WordPressDev/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/AisisCore/Template/Builder.php on line 69

Strict Standards: Accessing static property AisisCore_Template_Builder::$_options as non static in /home/kyle/WordPressDev/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/AisisCore/Template/Builder.php on line 70
```

which are fine and dandy for development environments but I have a production environment showing these errors, now I did set in my php.ini `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` and then I restarted Apache but still the same errors appear, while fixing them is awesome, I need these errors to go away in prod.

Comment: Have you tried `error_reporting = 0`?

Comment: What errors do you want to show? Does default php setting not work for you - `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` - all except notices? If you don't want any errors, disable them all, like @FritsvanCampen suggests, but the best thing is to fix those - they are shown for a reason!

Answer (score 2):

You should be hiding all kind of errors from the user in production and just log them.

To do so, set display_errors to Off

```
display_errors = Off
```

And just set error_reporting to log everything

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Comment: this did not work, if you visit: http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/ youll see that the errors are still there....

Comment: Try the solution in the link that Martyn suggested. But instead of using error_reporting, use `ini_set("display_errors", 0);` as it ensures that errors are still logged. If that doesn't work this could be to permissions on your host, apache/php not reloading configurations. The best way to test it is to create a php file on your server with the lines `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check whether the values have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~(E_DEPRECATED | E_STRICT)`.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-error-reporting-in-wordpress WordPress may be overriding the `php.ini` value.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `phpinfo()` to see path to your operational `php.ini`. perhaps there is another `php.ini` which system uses.